# How can I create a JavaScript dice?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dice in JavaScript. How does this work? I have got all the dice files/images ready on my PC. I want a button, so that the user can click to throw the dice.

Comment: How’s the “throw” supposed to look? Do you want animation? Should it simply display the cast? You should narrow what you ask, and also produce something you already have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something in HTML like this:

```
<script>

var face0=new Image()
face0.src="d1.gif"
var face1=new Image()
face1.src="d2.gif"
var face2=new Image()
face2.src="d3.gif"
var face3=new Image()
face3.src="d4.gif"
var face4=new Image()
face4.src="d5.gif"
var face5=new Image()
face5.src="d6.gif"
</script>


<img src="d1.gif" name="mydice">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Throw dice!" onClick="throwdice()">
</form>
<script>
function throwdice(){
var randomdice=Math.round(Math.random()*5)
document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face"+randomdice+".src")
}
</script>
```

source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dice.shtml

Comment: `eval("face"+randomdice+".src")` --- gosh, this is awful. Use arrays instead.

Comment: This seems to have been copied and stripped of comments from [here](http://shashnia.pbworks.com/w/page/16269366/javascript%20test).